# Recover log from python run in cmd line

Tags: python, cmd

I'm running python calling the code in the command line, and part of my script makes it print certain variables using lines such as:

```
utils.flush_print('time aout   = {0:1.3f}'.format(self.time_elapsed))
utils.flush_print('output_voltage_x_gain   = {0:1.3f}'.format(self.voltage_out))
```

I then get those variables printed in the cmd line in real time as the code is running. This program might be running for about 1 h, and when it is done, if I scroll up the cmd line, I can only see a few seconds worth of variable printed. Is there anyway to access the log from the cmd line from all the variables printed while the code was running? (I realize I could save the variables to some file while the code runs, but I'm wondering if I can read them of this cmd line history instead).

Comment: This is going to depend on what operating system and shell you are using. Adding that to your question will help you get better answers.

Comment: Based upon the [[tag:cmd]] tag, the shell is quite clearly the Microsoft Windows Command Prompt, `cmd.exe` @Kevin. I would assume that some mention of OS/2 would have been in the question if that was the OS. However the specific version of Windows would be useful to know. MelBasnak, what's stopping you from outputting everything to a file, then simply using `Type` or `More` to view it in the console upon completion?